# How to pause video playback when phone call is answered?

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I'm making an application for Windows Phone 8.1 using WinJS.

My application plays videos using the Microsoft Media Player framework.

Right now, when a phone call is answered, the video playback still continues and does not pause.

I'm looking for some event which I catch in my application and pause the video playback when a phone call is answered.

Comment: Hello, I've got to be missing something. When the call is answered your app should be moved to the background and be suspended. When the app is suspended it should stop the video. The only way I can think of that it could keep playing is if you are using background audio but I don't think we support audio / video playback from the background. Again, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.addEventListener('msvisibilitychange', function () {
     videoElement.pause();
 });
```

The [msvisibilitychange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441213.aspx) catches when the app is not visible anymore.